# VSCode debugger does not stop at breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging

I keep receiving this message while debugging:
`Module containing this breakpoint has not yet loaded or the breakpoint address could not be obtained.` Because of that I can not start debugging at the breakpoint I want. **The program keep running without stopping at the breakpoint.** I'm using VS Code.

**Here is my launch.json.**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is my task.json.**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "--debug",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My code is**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long int n,k,arr[1000];
    cin >> n;
    while (cin >> k){
        int j = 0;
        while (k != 0){
            arr[j] = k % 2;
            ++j;
            k = k / 2;
        }
        for (int i = j - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            cout << arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**The compile log**

```
PS D:\CODE\Learn_Space\Cpp> gcc nhap3.cpp                    
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(long&)'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(long)'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `std::istream::operator>>(long&)'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator bool() const'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::cout'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KHANG\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTaCzoJ.o:nhap3.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt3cin[.refptr._ZSt3cin]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::cin'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**The path in launch.json keep on changing every time I open VSCode**

**+ The path I want:**

```
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
```

**+ The path changed:**

```
 "cwd": "d:/CODE/Learn_Space/Cpp",
 "program": "d:/CODE/Learn_Space/Cpp/build/Debug/outDebug",
```

Even though I reset the path correctly, I still can not start debugging.

I tried adding the `"-g"` into the task.json as you can see above, but it seems to be not working at all. Am I missing something? Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? Thank you so much <3

Comment: Can you please provide the compile log? Also the code would be helpful.

Comment: you mean the terminal message right? I have added the code into my post

Comment: no when you compile using `gcc` or similar

Comment: how exactly are you starting debugging? it doesn't look like you're using your build task.

Comment: @Yann I have updated the details in the post

Comment: @starball I use F5, or click on the `Start Debugging` button

Comment: what if you use the run/debug view and click the play button there after selecting your launch config?

Comment: It seems you are compiling at all. As your log returns an error. For Windows if using `gcc` you need cross compiling Tools. It can be a nightmare to set accordingly the path. I think you need mingw or similar.

Comment: @starball it's not working, the result is the same

Comment: @Yann I have already downloaded the mingw but I need to re-download it right?

Comment: Don't know why guys but every time I close and re-open the VSCode, the path in launch.json just keep on changing. It really annoying. Anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Sometimes I realized that you have to set the breakpoint before entering debug, otherwise it is ignored. It is not a consistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I trace the overall install process to first debug. Your issue is not the breakpoint, it is your build process which fails.

For example my compile looks like this:

> Starting build... /usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g
> /home/yg/testcode/.vscode/main.cpp -o /home/yg/testcode/.vscode/main
>
> Build finished successfully.  *  Terminal will be reused by tasks,
> press any key to close it.

I think your task code is correct, it's look like mine:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

I would also suggest to delete the launch file I think it is not required.

Next steps I would suggest:

- Make sure your compiler is located under "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
- Compile the hello world:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

- Add the breakpoint at line 5. In my case the code stops there